# .xlsx downloading issue in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python development.

I am developing a flask API in Python that will help to download one excel file in `.xlsx` format.
my code is generating the file in `.xlsx` format but when I downloading the report I am getting the error: `"File format or file extensions are not valid. Verify the file has not been corrupted"`.

Please help me on this.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from flask import send_file

def get_data():
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    with pd.ExcelWriter(buf, date_format='dd/mm/yyyy', datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as test:
        dtl_ext = detail.to_excel(test, index=False,encoding='utf-16')
        detail_rec.save()
        excel_data = buf.getvalue()
        buf.seek(0)
        return send_file(
            buf,
            mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            attachment_filename='test11.xlsx',
            as_attachment=True,
            cache_timeout=0
        )
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html), it looks like `ExcelWriter` only takes a file path and not a buffer, unlike other pandas functions

Comment: I have seen in one example in the below link where ExcelWriter accepts buffer
https://community.plot.ly/t/allow-users-to-dowload-an-excel-in-a-click/9410/8

Comment: if anybody can help on this, it will be really appreciated.
I need this

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your code, but the example you linked does not use a context manager. Have you tried without the context manager. I don't know what your issue is, but since you have an example, try to replicate that and see where the issue occurs.

Comment: Hi, I have added my code.
Here my issue is i am able to download the excel file test11.xlsx, but the file is getting corrupted with zero bytes.

Comment: what is context manager, how I can use this?

Comment: The `with` statement is called a context manager in Python. The example you linked to does not use `with`, but you do, so I am wondering if that is the issue.

Comment: with pd.ExcelWriter(buf, date_format='dd/mm/yyyy', datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as test:
Here I have used with

Comment: anywhere also I have to use WITH?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following libraries to make it easier:

- http://flask.pyexcel.org/en/latest/
- https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xls
- https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx

After you have installed them (check the links for that). Import them in Python in the following manner:

- `import flask_excel as excel`
- `import pyexcel.ext.xls`
- `import pyexcel.ext.xlsx`

Then:

```
@app/route('/download', methods=['GET'])
def download_data():
    sample_data=[0, 1, 2]
    excel.init_excel(app)
    extension_type = "xlsx"
    filename = "test123" + "." extension_type
    d = {'colName': sample_data}
    return excel.make_response_from_dict(d, file_type=extension_type, file_name=filename)
    # check the flask-excel library from different export option. 
    # This one uses a dictionary of lists. 
    # You can do a lists of dictionary, simply an array, so on and so forth
```

Comment: with newer versions of pyexcel, 'import pyexcel.ext.xls' is no longer required.